# Colorbox: Open external link in separate window/tab and keep colorbox open

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox to display course info for a college (see [page](http://culinaryconferencecenter.com/cooking_classes.htm)). In each pop-up is a button that links to a class registration page which I'd like to open in an external window or tab. Using a standard a tag with a target="_blank" doesn't work (see all but the first course (Advanced Cake Decorating I) - the pop-up shrinks to an empty window. I can get it to work by attaching a window.open() function to an onclick event, but that also shrinks the pop-up. I'd like to open the class registration link in it's own window/tab and keep the colorbox pop-up open for reference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best - Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the click handler window.open technique, but then prevent the event bubbling on the click event?

eg:

```
    $(".mylink").click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        window.open( ... );
    });
```

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad it helped. Do you mind "accepting" the answer to boost my rep?